# Chaining logical operators

Tags: c, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

I have some trouble chaining logical operators. I'm certain that I'm messing something up but I do not see it.

I have tried various combinations of this (like adding parentheses around every "not equal to" operation etc.):

```c
if (a != b && (a != EOF || b != EOF)) {
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

But nothing works. `a` and `b` are bits read from a file with `fgetc`, I can provide more code. But since this is about chaining logical operators I assume that this is enough.

If it's not apparent, I want the if condition execute if `a` and `b` are different but *not* when one of them equals `EOF`.

Comment: Tell us what the _types_ and values of `a` and `b` are, and what you expect to happen

Comment: Do you perhaps want `a != EOF && b != EOF`?

Comment: @TimRandall they are `int`s. I realised that I didn't explain it, I already made a edit

Comment: @dbush made a edit to the post

Comment: @user419050 Reading the edit, that sounds like a yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating what you said to code:

```
// I want the if condition execute:
// if    a and b are different    but  not when one of them equals EOF
   if (  a != b                   &&   !   (a == EOF || b == EOF) )
```

Then applying DeMorgan's rule which moves the NOT inside and switches the OR to an AND:

```
   if ( a != b  &&  a != EOF && b != EOF )
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon what dbush said in a comment, you want to "do stuff" if `a` is different to `b`, and `a` is not EOF, and `b` is not EOF. That is most simply expressed in code as

```
if( a != b && a != EOF && b != EOF)...
```

(Bear in mind that `EOF` is a negative value, which cannot be stored in an `unsigned` variable.)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a problem to write a condition then at first try to write a condition for which the sub-statement of the if statement will be bypassed.

For your if statement the false condition will look like

```
a == b || a == EOF || b == EOF
```

then use its negation

```
if ( !( a == b || a == EOF || b == EOF ) )
```

Now it can be rewritten like

```
if ( !( a == b ) && !( a == EOF ) && !( b == EOF ) )
```

that in turn will look like

```
if ( a != b && a != EOF && b != EOF )
```

Answer (score -1):

try ( a!=b && a != EOF || a!=b && b!= EOF )